# Incomplete declaration of a partially specialized template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, hash, c++14

I am trying to partially specialize the `std::hash` struct for my own class `TestHandle`, and this class has its implementation split up using the opaque pointer idiom.  So I am trying to provide the `impl` class with its own `std::hash` specialization.  But I am running into templating problems.

Could someone help me understand why this is happening?  I have attached all the necessary code below.

**TestHandle.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>

class TestHandle {
public:
    TestHandle();

    void print();

    class Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> implementation;
};
```

**TestHandle.cpp**

```
#include "TestHandle.h"
#include "Impl.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

TestHandle::TestHandle() : implementation{new TestHandle::Impl} { }

void TestHandle::print() {
    this->implementation->print();
    cout << "Hash of this->implementation is " 
        << std::hash<TestHandle::Impl>()(*this->implementation) << endl;
}
```

**Impl.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "TestHandle.h"
#include <functional>

class TestHandle::Impl {
public:

    void print();
    int inner_integer;
};

namespace std {
    template <> struct std::hash<TestHandle::Impl>;
}
```

**Impl.cpp**

```
#include "TestHandle.h"
#include "Impl.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#include <functional>

namespace std {
    template <> struct hash <TestHandle::Impl> {
        size_t operator() (const TestHandle::Impl& implementation) {
            return std::hash<int>()(implementation.inner_integer);
        }
    };
}

void TestHandle::Impl::print() {
    cout << "Printing from impl" << endl;
}
```

I am compiling with the following command

```
g++ -std=c++14 -c Impl.cpp TestHandle.cpp
```

and am getting the following error

```
TestHandle.cpp:11:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'std::hash<TestHandle::Impl>'
<< std::hash<TestHandle::Impl>()(*this->implementation) << endl;
```

Comment: You should include `<functional>` before trying to special `std::hash` iirc, that is where the primary template is defined

Comment: Thank you! I will update my post

Comment: Another problem is, the template is not visible in one of the compilation units where it is used. `TestHandle.cpp` needs to see the implementation, but hte implementation is in `impl.cpp`. So you should move the implementation to the header instead.

Comment: But can this not be treated as a function call since it is a specialization?  If I had a function call separated as such in two files this would run ok?

Comment: yes if it were just a function call, it would be ok, but for a template, no. You could forward declare a little helper function, and make the template `std::hash` method `operator()` call the helper function, and have the helper implementation in a single compilation unit. and that would be okay. But when a template is instantiated, in any compilation unit, the definition needs to be visible, or instantiation can't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <> struct std::hash<TestHandle::Impl>;
```

Just forward declares the specialisation. It doesn't have to implement all the method (or any) of the original template. The compiler has no idea about the `operator()`.

You will need to define the `struct` (in place of just the declaration);

```
template <> struct hash <TestHandle::Impl> {
        size_t operator() (const TestHandle::Impl& implementation) const noexcept;
    };
```

*Side note: you will also need to provide the primary template (via inclusion) of `<functional>` (missing in the original listed code).*

Comment: That should be fine, but the definition needs to be visible.

Comment: How do I go about doing that?  If I have a function declaration and definition this works fine...  I want to keep the implementations separate from the modules